# Yii2: How do I debug console commands?

Tags: php, debugging, console, yii2, command-line-interface

The Yii2 debugger seems to only work for web requests. How can I debug console commands (CLI)?

Eg. I need to see the SQL statements that were executed during a console command...

Answer (score 2):

Use logger:

```
'log' => [
'targets' => [[
    ...
], [
    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
    'logFile' => '@runtime/logs/profile.log',
    'logVars' => [],
    'levels' => ['profile'],
    'categories' => ['yii\db\Command::query'],
    'prefix' => function($message) {
        return '';
    }
]]
```

]

Comment: One more attribute `'microtime' => true,` helps a lot to see SQL performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/achertovsky/yii2-debug-cli

i wrote extension to existing yii2-debug to achieve the result. Please, use and lmk issues if you find some.

Answer (score 0):

In the Yii2 default application advanced template, you already have the log file target setup/enabled. However, it is only enabled for 'error' and 'warning' conditions. To include for info, add info as below in the console/config/main.php

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
    'levels' => ['info', 'error', 'warning'],
],
```

The log output should be in console/runtime/logs/app.log